# Mercurial (or generally in any VCS): find diffs in moved file

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial, an old commit that's of interest to me consists of moving many files from one directory to another. These files have also been changed at some points (mostly: because references needed to be updated). These changes are of interest to me. However, when I examine the diff (using "hg export -r REVNO") I am presented with stuff of the following form:

```
diff -r 8cd7ce03f753 -r 98a582c2fca4 oldpath/path/to/file
--- a/oldpath/path/to/file       Tue Aug 12 15:35:09 2014 +0200
+++ /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
- a lot of stuff
- more stuff
- unchanged stuff
- file continues

... the same for c. 100 other files ...

diff -r 8cd7ce03f753 -r 98a582c2fca4 newpath/path/to/file
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/newpath/path/to/file  Tue Aug 12 16:02:42 2014 +0200
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+ a lot of stuff
+ more stuff
+ changed stuff
+ file continues

... the same for c. 100 other files ...
```

In the above the difference between "unchanged" and "changed" can be deduced manually. However, I'd like my tooling to help me and present this difference to me automatically. Ideally across all files of the commit. However, even if I can point at a single file (and its renamed version) that would already be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Add `--git` to the `hg export` invocation.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful

Comment: Maybe so, but why don't you just try it?

Comment: Try what? I don't even know what this is. Your answer was flagged as low quality, which is why I said to add some explanation

Comment: adding --git to the hg export invocation doesn't magically fix the problem for me (oldpath/.../file and newpath/.../file are still shown separately as a full removal and full add), so an explanation of why you think it should would be nice.

Comment: Then your Mercurial behaves very strangely. For me, it shows just a regular diff, as if the file name had been the same all along.